# Complex layout in Unity

Tags: unity, gui

I need ScrollRect, but at startup I don't know how many elements it should keep. Moreover this elements should be kept in categories that can fold/unfold.

[image]
The problem is that height of `content` doesn't updates after folding/unfolding. This worked in Unity 5 with ContentSizeFitter in `content` and each category, but this doesn't work with Unity 2017.

Items are added at runtime with instantiating from prefab in a certain category.

Is there any solutions without additional scripting?

**EDIT**

Additional screenshots
[image]
When unfolded can't scroll anything because `content` size is too small

[image]
This is script part for instantiating items inside categories.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the object hierarchy in the inspector after it's generated, and add your script code? It's hard to help without having something to look at, and I doubt anyone is going to comb through patch notes for you.

Answer (score 1):

"Children should also have a `ContentSizeFitter` to change their height in order for parent `ContentSizeFitter` to change its height." - that was my mistake. It's not true that children should have it. What is important is that `ContentSizeFitter` - doesn't have a clue what behaviour it should use to fit all the content. For example, you have multiple child elements with `width: 100` and `height: 50`, you have `3` of them. They are all placed in content that has `ContentSizeFitter` on it. While you would expect `ContentSizeFitter` to add all the bounding boxes and calculate it's own bounding box it doesn't do that.

[image: Content Fitter Example]

**Why?** - Because it needs some kind of trigger that will define it's behaviour.

**And what can serve as this trigger?** - Layout components.

[image: Vertical Group + Content Fitter]

`LayoutGroup` component tells `ContentSizeFitter` that it has this width and this height or (it depends on internal implementation) `ContentSizeFitter` gets width and height from some `Layout Group` that calculates those bounds. It's worth a try to create a custom `LayoutGroup` component that calculates bounds as required for your project. But in most cases `Grid`, `Vertical` and `Horizontal` are enough to achieve the desired results.

If native component doesn't work as required then you may as well write your own, or extend the behaviour of a current one.

Here is an example of how additional functionality can be added to the component:

```
[AddComponentMenu("Layout/Advanced Content Size Fitter", 141)]
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class AdvancedContentSizeFitter : ContentSizeFitter
{
    protected RectTransform m_rectTransfrom;

    [SerializeField] protected Vector2 m_minSize = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    [SerializeField] protected Vector2 m_maxSize = new Vector2(250f, 250f);

    protected override void OnRectTransformDimensionsChange()
    {
        base.OnRectTransformDimensionsChange();

        if (this.m_rectTransfrom == null)
            this.m_rectTransfrom = this.transform as RectTransform;

        this.m_rectTransfrom.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(this.m_rectTransfrom.sizeDelta.x, this.m_minSize.x, this.m_maxSize.x), Mathf.Clamp(this.m_rectTransfrom.sizeDelta.y, this.m_minSize.y, this.m_maxSize.y));
    }

    protected override void OnEnable()
    {
        base.OnEnable();

        this.m_rectTransfrom = this.transform as RectTransform;
    }
}
```

This one basically adds min, max size to the component behaviour while keeping the previous behaviour.